# Get distinct values and case insensitive with MongoDb

Tags: php, mongodb

Is it possible to get distinct values and be case insensitive?  I found a couple people saying to use the aggregate function but I would keep getting errors like: exception: field path references must be prefixed with a '$' ('Classification'.

```
public function getDistinctValues($cid, $table, $column)
{
  $mongo = new MongoClient();
  $db = $mongo->leadworks;

  $collection = new MongoCollection($db, $table);
  //$result = $collection->distinct($column);

  $result = $collection->aggregate(array(
    array(
      '$unwind' => $column,
    ),
    array(
      '$group' => array(
        '_id' => array(
          '$toLower' => array(
            $column,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ));

  return $result;
}
```

This is how my document looks:

```
   {  
     _id:2065565,
     Date:new Date(1411732940000),
     Email:"email@email.com",
     Other - Industry:null,
     Other - Job Duties:null,
     First Name:"Test Name",
     Last Name:"Test Last Name",
     Title:"engineer",
     Company:"Company Name Here",
     Country:"UNITED STATES",
     State:"MI",
     Zipcode:"48071-1514",
     Phone number:"777-777-7777",
     Company type:"Systems integration",
  }
```

I'm specifically trying to get distinct values for Company and ignore case.

Comment: When this is a common and performance-sensitive query you might consider to store two versions of the string in different fields, one in mixed case and one in upper-case. This does not just make case-insensitive queries a lot easier to write, it also allows to speed them up with an index.

Comment: What do your documents look like?

Comment: @JuanCarlosFarah I added my document to the question.